# Display user data in template

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Django. I want to display in templates
user's information where he connect, but when I change page, data disappears!

***views.py:***

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username', None)
        password = request.POST.get('password', None)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        data = {}
        data['user'] = user

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_authenticated:
                return redirect(accueil)

            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Compte inactif.')

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Identifiant et/ou mot de passe invalide.')

     return render(request, 'login.html')
```

***Models.py:***

```
class AbstractCustomerUser(AbstractBaseUser):
        """
        An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
        admin-compliant permissions.

        Username, password and email are required. Other fields are optional.
        """
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and '
                    '@/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(r'^[\w.@+-]+$', _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
        ])


    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    referent_for_customers = models.ManyToManyField('Customer',
                                                    related_name='referents',
    verbose_name="est référent pour")

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['id', 'company']

    class Meta:
        # For an unknown reason, fails to save a modified object with this
        # constaint. Comment it for now:
        #unique_together = ('username', 'company')
        verbose_name = _('utilisateur')
        abstract = True

    class CustomerUser(AbstractCustomerUser):
        class Meta(AbstractCustomerUser.Meta):
            db_table = 'customers_customeruser'
            swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
            verbose_name = 'utilisateur portail'
```

***templates:***

```
<div id="header">
   <h2>Portail Client</h2>
   Bienvenue {{ user.username }}

   CustomerUser table info: {{ user.company_id }}, {{ user.last_login }} 
   Customer table info:  {{ user.company.name }}

   <a href="/referents/password_change/">Modifier mot de passe</a>
   <a href="/referents/logout/">Déconnexion</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` is automatically provided to the template via the context processor. But these only run if you are using a `RequestContext` when rendering your template: either by specifically passing it in (eg with the `context_instance` parameter to `render_to_response`), or by using the newer `render` shortcut.

So in all your other views, you need to be sure you are doing:

```
return render(request, 'your_template.html', params)
```

Comment: Yes, if I do working with `return render(request, 'accueil.html', data)` no problem, informations display right but if I change page nothing more :p

Comment: As I said, you have to use that function on *every* view.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the user object is not available inside your template. If the user object is not available in the template, nothing will be displayed when the template evaluates `{{ user.username }}`

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables) -

> If you use a variable that doesn’t exist, the template system will
>   insert the value of the TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID setting, which is
>   set to '' (the empty string) by default.

You can pass the user object to the template by modifying the appropriate view which returns the welcome template, using either `render()` which forces the use of a `RequestContext` implicitly or `render_to_response()` where you have to explicitly pass a `RequestContext` instance

Answer (score 0):

in your views.py you should use RequestContext

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def login(request):
args={}
...
return render_to_response('login.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: render is a shortcut function for render_to_response fyi